# C# TMDbClient HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#

I'm using the TMDbLib https://www.nuget.org/packages/TMDbLib/ 1.9.2 (upgraded due to error bellow) to grab info about TV shows. Until a day or so ago, this has been working.

Some aspects are still working. I've checked my API Key, and that is valid.

I'm getting the following errors

```
    // Access to The Movie DB API
    TMDbClient client = new TMDbClient(<API KEY>);
```

Error: but no exception

```
'client.Config' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Then

`var NewEpisode = client.GetTvEpisodeAsync(TMDBid, SeasonNumber, Epnum).Result;`

Error: with exceptions
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]

```
Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Inner Exception 3:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Inner Exception 4:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Are these related, and how might I fix this? BTW I have Fast internet.

Comment: Check your firewall once and add the exception for the Program if necessary.

Comment: Turned of firewall and added  try except bloke still errors also tried in an MS azure VM same results

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed this

Putting here in case someone else has similar issues

themoviedb.org uses TLS 1.3
Turns out I was using an older version of .NET framework that doesn't support TLS 1.3
Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
and
[The request was aborted could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855415/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-httpwebrequest)

Uninstalled TMDBLib and System.Net.Http
Updated to newer .Net Framework

Reinstalled TMDBLib, System.Net.Http is a dependency so gets installed by default